# i want to make a new processor of payment for PayU in joomla

Tags: joomla, components, payment, payu

I am using acctexp component in joomla. this have several processors for payment but i have to use PayU which is not included in this. i want to convert anyone from these processors to PayU but can't do. Actually i am new to joomla. Please any one help.

Comment: I am unable to find this component acctexp component. Which component is this? Does it have any other payment plugin? Can I upload the component is google drive or somewhere and send the link?

Answer (score 0):

You can write own for your requirement basis.Below link may be useful

https://www.payumoney.com/websiteintegration.html

https://github.com/techjoomla/joomla-payments/tree/master/code/plugins/payu

Comment: with which component it will use : https://github.com/techjoomla/joomla-payments/tree/master/code/plugins/payu

Comment: may be this is an earlier version. do you have link with latest version 3x.

Comment: Understand we do not have plugin for your requirement . you can develop own, i gave only the refer documents